# ndb independent transactions and retry

Tags: google-app-engine, app-engine-ndb

I have a problem finding a detailed explanation of datastore behaviour in the following scenario.

1. A transaction is started
2. Some changes are made
3. Another, independent, transaction is started using ndb.TransactionOptions.INDEPENDENT propagation level. It's purpose is to increment a sharded counter. I need it as a nested transaction, because I'll have many counters and it's only possible to use 5 entity groups in one transaction
4. Nested transaction is committing successfully
5. Main transaction is trying to commit, but fails
6. Main transaction is committing after some retries

I suppose that nested transaction is run only once, but I cannot verify this assumption.
Does anybody know how it works?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put some logging statements in to see the behavior. If steps 3-4 are initiated by the code of the main transaction, the independent transaction will be started each time the main transaction is retried. That's why it's called INDEPENDENT, not NESTED.

Comment: I understand that my assumption is wrong and I need some other mechanism. May I assume that transactional task enqueuing if free from the problem of duplicating during transaction retry?

Comment: One more thing came to my mind. I don't know how to reproduce app engine retry mechanism in a predictable way. Your remark about logging made me think that it's easy. Is app engine retry functionality any different from just calling transaction function multiple times?

Comment: You haven't explained what you are trying to do. But yes the transaction function just gets called until the transaction succeeds or until the retry count.  Transactional task enqueueing indeed enqueues only when the transaction succeeds.

Comment: Thanks. Now I have the feeling that I understand how it works and that's important to me. The specific problem I tried to solve was to increment a number of sharded counters as a result of the transaction. When I realized, that there are more of them than is allowed in one transaction I enclosed them in a separate transactions. Now I see that transactional task queue is the right solution